# how retrieve only selected checkbox values in action class in struts 1.3

Tags: checkbox, struts, struts-action

i am new struts i am developing web application in which i have a requirement that i have to show records in tabular format i have made use of display tag in struts with every record i have a checkbox now i need to retrieve the values of those checkboxes in my Action which are checked . but what i am receiving in Action array of all the checkboxes. actually while displaying checkboxes by making use of display tag all checkbobes have got same name therefore i am not understanding how handle this care i have searched on google but did not find suitable situation

```
<display:column  title="Service">
<input type="checkbox" name="sercive" />
</display:column>
```

how to handle this situation not understanding .could anyone give some sample code
or hint to handle this situation

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about display tag.
But in struts you have to define a property in Form bean (i.e. ActionForm) of type String[] or List with the name same as defined for your check boxes.
Then in Action class you will get the array of selected checkboxes only.

If this is not working. Then you can try of getting the values using request.getParameter("service"). This will return comma separated list of selected checkboxes which you can convert to array using split() method and then you can continue with your logic.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Plain HTML checkboxes are only submitted if they're checked, that's just how clients work.

You must provide a differentiating factor, generally a value (e.g., a service ID in your case), to determine which has been selected. Your action form would contain a collection of those IDs.